# Killing Vector Fields of Schwarzschild

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

It is known that the vector fields $\partial_t$, $\partial_\phi$, $\sin \phi \partial_\theta+\cot \theta \cos\phi \partial_\phi$, and $\cos\phi \partial_\theta-\cot \theta\sin \phi\partial_\phi$ are Killing vector fields of Schwarzschild. $\partial_t$ is evidently Killing since the metric components of the Schwarzschild metric do not depend and $t$, and the remaining Killing vector fields are the Killing vector fields on the sphere.

A priori, it is not clear why these generate the entire Lie algebra Killing vector fields. How can we know that indeed these vector fields generate this Lie algebra?

Comment: What do you mean by "generate"?

Comment: By that I mean span!

Comment: This question might be better for the physics stack exchange: https://physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: The space of Killing vector fields on the sphere is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{so}(3)$, which is 3 dimensional, so you're evidently missing one.